# I am trying to redirect the VF page based on record type ID by using PageRefernce

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, urlhacking

VF Page:

```
  <apex:page controller="RecordTypeController">
     <apex:form>
          <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                 <apex:commandButton value="Continue" action="{!editWithRecordType}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>

             <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="1">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!proxy.RecordTypeId}"/>        

              </apex:pageBlockSection>

                 </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
             </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class RecordTypeController {


           public opportunity proxy { get; set; }


    public RecordTypeController() {
            proxy = new opportunity();
    }


        public PageReference editWithRecordType() {
      pagereference pa1;

          List< RecordType> rt= [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'];
            system.debug(rt);

            for(RecordType rt1 : rt ) 
            {
                Id id='012b0000000M8s5AAC';
          if(  rt1.Id==id)
        {
        pa1= new PageReference('/apex/OppExtension');

        }
        else   
         {   
        pa1= new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType='+rt1.id+' &ent=Opportunity');
            } 
        } 
            system.debug(pa1);
        return pa1;


}}
```

The condition is not redirecting to IF condition. And it is taking directly first record id of the list in ELSE condition. Please help there is issue in iterating list. Records type id's are being fetched perfectly in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep if else condition outside of for loop and inside for loop ,you need to keep boolean to check if it matches with recordtype.
you the below code :

```
public class RecordTypeController {
    public opportunity proxy { get; set; }
    public RecordTypeController() {
            proxy = new opportunity();
    }

    public PageReference editWithRecordType() {
        pagereference pa1;
        List< RecordType> rt= [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'];
        system.debug(rt);
        Id recordTypeId ='012b0000000M8s5AAC';
        Boolean isRecordTypeExist = false;
        for(RecordType rt1 : rt ) { 
            
            if(  rt1.Id==recordTypeId) {
                isRecordTypeExist = true;
            }
        
        } 
        if(isRecordTypeExist == true) {
            pa1= new PageReference('/apex/OppExtension');
        } else {
            pa1= new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&RecordType='+rt1.id+' &ent=Opportunity');
        }
        system.debug(pa1);
        return pa1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying every single record type regardless of the user selection, and going through the entire list, so naturally, you'll get the same results every time. Instead, you will want to do something like the following:

```
    public PageReference editWithRecordType() {
      RecordType specialRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='Opportunity' AND Name='My Special Record Type'];
      if(proxy.RecordTypeId==specialRecordType.Id) {
        return Page.OppExtension;
      } else {
        return new PageReference('/006/e?RecordType='+proxy.RecordTypeId+'&ent=Opportunity');
      }
    }
```